# A question about notation of convergence of sequences

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $x_n \to x $ means that for given $\epsilon > 0$, we can find some $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $|x_n - x| < \epsilon $.

MY question is: What does $x_n \uparrow x$ and $x_n \downarrow x$ mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means that you have an increasing sequence that converges to $x$.
(and the opposite).